# How to get row count for some specific condition

Tags: cassandra

I m using cassandra. is there a way to get a row count (key count) of a single column family in Cassandra for some specific condition?

(for example select * from user where salary>=5000 in mysql)

get_count can only be used to get the column count.

Answer (score 3):

[Secondary index](http://www.riptano.com/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-secondary-indexes) will solve your problems. (Secondary index lets your query on column values)

Comment: It will mostly solve your problems.  You can ask to get 0 columns back from your query, but you will still get back all of the keys for matching rows.  If all you really want is a count, set up a counter.

Comment: @Schildmeijer i m using cassandra 0.6.8 so will indexedslcequery support it?Actually I tried to use IndexSliceQuery in my java program but its saying create this class.so what could be the issue.?

Comment: @Schildmeijer if i upgrade Cassandra from 0.6.8 to Cassandra 0.7,will it create impact on my existing data..?

Comment: No the data will be fine. But Cassandra nodes running 0.6.x will not be compatible with 0.7.x nodes

Comment: @Schildmeijer thank you for your reply.Sir then what how can i do for the node compatibility.is there any way for this?